# Asp.NET Core DataAnotationLocalization not returning validation results from correct language

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am creating my first asp.net core app and I am trying to create modelstate localizaed validation messages.

Here is what  have done so far.In my Startup class I have the following:

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       //Omitted code because is not relevant to curent problem 

       var mvc = services.AddMvc(config => {
            config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandler(env));
            config.Filters.Add(new LanguageActionFilter());
        });

        mvc.AddViewLocalization();

        mvc.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

    }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
       //Omitted code because is not relevant to curent problem 

        UseLocalization(app);

        UseMvcConfig(app);
    }

    private void UseLocalization(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var defaultCulture = new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("ro-RO"));

        var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("ro-RO")
            },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("ro-RO")
            }
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions, defaultCulture);
    }

    private void UseMvcConfig(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc(config =>
        {
            config.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I am making a post call to the following controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMapperService mapperService;
        private readonly IAuthenticationManager autheticationManager;
        private readonly IUserManager userManager;

        public AccountController(IUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager autheticationManager, IMapperService mapperService)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.mapperService = mapperService;
            this.autheticationManager = autheticationManager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ModelStateValidation]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]UserRegistrationViewModel userViewModel)
        {
            UserDTO userDTO = mapperService.Map<UserRegistrationViewModel, UserDTO>(userViewModel);
            IdentityResult registrationResult = await userManager.RegisterAsync(userDTO, Request.Host.Value);

            if (!registrationResult.Succeeded) {
                return HttpBadRequest();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

And my UserRegistrationViewModel looks like this:

```
    [Mapper(MapTo = typeof(UserDTO))]
public class UserRegistrationViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Account_Register_EmailAddress", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Account_Register_Password", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Account_Register_Password_Confirmation", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Account_Register_Password_Compared", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I have also created two resouce files. One is called Resource.resx and the other Resource.ro-RO.resx.

Now when an ajax call gets executed from the client I will set the following 
aditional header:

```
'Accept-Language': 'ro-RO'
```

My problem is that instead of returning the data from Resource.ro-RO.resx it returns the ones from Resource.resx.

I have also checked to see what is the current CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture and they are both set to 'ro-RO'.

What am I missing?